# hstore: cannot concatenate two hstore values

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

New to Postgres, using v9.3, want to leverage `hstore`.

When I try to concatenate two `hstore` values I get a weird error:

```
SELECT p.properties->'name' || p.properties->'age' FROM people p where p.id=1;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: select n.properties->'name' || n.properties->'age' from n...
                                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried this too, and it didn't matter:

```
SELECT p.properties->'name'::text || p.properties->'age'::text FROM people p where p.id=1;
```

However, I *can* do

```
SELECT p.properties->'name' FROM people p where p.id=1;

SELECT p.properties->'age' FROM people p where p.id=1;
```

Is it not possible to concatenate two hstore values out of the same hstore?

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with the **CAST** function as is :

```
SELECT CAST(p.properties->'name' AS text) || CAST(p.properties->'age' AS text) FROM people p where p.id=1;
```

Comment: That fixes the issue. Turns out you only have to CAST the second and subsequent hstore references, the first can remain unadorned. Weird. Thanks for the help!